# cannot find the sql generated by jhipster create entity

Tags: jhipster

I have done setup of jhipster(using [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQ6nnJGKba4) ) and tried to create entity using jhipster. I have not taken any json file as input. To make it simple I have created entity Employee as....

Command     yo jhipster:entity Employee

---Employee---

name String

email String

---

with no validation rules and relationship. Entity creation is successful but I cannot find any .sql file containing the sql command.
I can see respective java files are generated in under src\main\java\com\mycompany\myapp\domain. Any idea where is the sql created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no generated SQL files.
JHipster uses Liquibase for the changes to your Database. 
You should have these XML files in `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/`, doing the same as SQL files.

Comment: yes, indeed. but any tool that creates SQL out of these liquibase xml files?

Comment: Not that I know, and not by JHipster. But quick search on Google/StackOverFlow, you'll have some answers to your last question.

Comment: liquibase command has an SQL output option https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_output.html